# APEX unit test error - cannot reference converted lead

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

i create the trigger and unit test for convert lead process, the trigger seems work, but the unit test code has error.

here is the trigger code

```
trigger ConvLeadtrigg02 on Lead (after insert, after update) {

    Database.LeadConvert[] leadCollectionArray = new Database.LeadConvert[]{};
    for(Lead mylead : trigger.new){
        if(mylead.Ready_to_Convert__c == true){
            Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
            lc.setLeadId(mylead.Id);
            lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted');
            lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(true);
            leadCollectionArray.add(lc);
        }
    }
    Database.LeadConvertResult[] lcr = Database.convertLead(leadCollectionArray,false);
}
```

here is the unit test code

```
@isTest
private class UnitTest_ConvLeadtrigg02 {

    static testMethod void ConvLeadtrigg02() {

       test.StartTest();

       // Create the Lead object
       Lead testLead = new Lead(
           FirstName='Demo name800',
           LastName = 'Demo name888 UnitTest',
           Status='Prospect',
           Ready_to_Convert__c = true
       );

       insert testLead;
       System.debug('Created and inserted lead');

       Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
       lc.setLeadId(testLead.Id);

       LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
       lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);
       Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
       System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

       test.stopTest();
   }
}
```

Please help to check, thanks

Comment: whats the erro?

Comment: In the future, please try and format your code properly to make it easier to read. I have gone ahead and formatted for you here, but you will get better feedback in the future if you give well written questions.

Comment: What is this Lead trigger behavior supposed to be doing and when and under what conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Once a lead is converted, the Lead record cannot be updated. Your trigger will need to check the leads in the update operation to ensure that they have not already been converted, else you will receive an error. "cannot reference converted lead"

The Lead object has an `IsConverted` property that you can check to see if it has been converted.

You should be able to simply change the if statement in your code block to include this field.

```
if(myLead.isConverted && mylead.Ready_to_Convert__c == true){
```

Comment: hi, Mark, thanks, i did modify the condition check part as suggest, something like

change under APEX trigger
if((myLead.isConverted == false) && (mylead.Ready_to_Convert__c == true)){

other code here...

}
But, the error still occur under unit test code which is need to modify as well i guess. Thanks

Comment: @webon100 can you post the solution to the problem as an answer of your own and then accept that answer or accept one of the answers given?